# Get Shortcode Attributes

Tags: shortcode

I am building a shortcode. I would love for the array with the category names "$catslugs" to be added via the shortcode. But reading the stuff on wordpress.org confuses me. The code below is partial. This simple shortcode works: [camp_posts] (more below code)

```
function camp_posts_function() {//Creates shortcode [camp_posts]

$catslugs = array('academic', 'adventure', 'arts', 'religious', 'special-interest', 'special-needs', 'sports','teen');//Must update as new Main categories are added 
$out = array();
foreach($catslugs as $slug) {
    array_push($out, get_category_by_slug($slug)->term_id);
    }
$CatIDs= implode(',', $out);

$camp_posts_bynumber = new WP_Query(array ('cat' => $CatIDs));

if( $camp_posts_bynumber->have_posts() ):
```

I want that array with "academic, adventure..." to be pulled in from the shortcode. I added "type" to my shortcode which was just [camp_posts] using the above code and now is [camp_posts type="academic, sports"]. I'm just not sure how to grab the info. I know it needs to be something like this:

```
function camp_posts_function($atts) {//Creates shortcode [camp_posts]
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'type' => 1,
   ), $atts));
$out = array();
foreach($atts as $slug) {
    array_push($out, get_category_by_slug($slug)->term_id);
    }
$CatIDs= implode(',', $out);
$camp_posts_bynumber = new WP_Query(array ('cat' => $CatIDs));

if( $camp_posts_bynumber->have_posts() ):
```

After fiddling some more, I am closer:

```
function camp_posts_function($atts) {//Creates shortcode [camp_posts]
$atts=shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type' => 'nothing',
        ), $atts, 'camp_posts');
 return $atts['type'];
```

That returns "academic, sports". But I am unsure how to get it into $catslugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. With the shortcode set as [camp_posts type="academic, sports"] the code that does the trick is this:

```
function camp_posts_function($atts) {//Creates shortcode [camp_posts type="academics, sports"]
$atts=shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type' => 'nothing',
        ), $atts, 'camp_posts');
$ShortcodeAtts=esc_attr($atts['type']);//Puts "type" attribute into a variable
$ShortcodeAttsArray = explode(',', $ShortcodeAtts);

$IDout = array();//Initializes array
foreach($ShortcodeAttsArray as $slug) {
    array_push($IDout, get_category_by_slug($slug)->term_id);//Gets category ID of each category slug name
    }
$CatIDs= implode(',', $IDout);//Puts all category IDs into variable $CatIDs with a commas between

$camp_posts_bynumber = new WP_Query(array ('cat' => $CatIDs));

if( $camp_posts_bynumber->have_posts() ):
```